# How to know what the values passed in golang template?

Tags: go, go-templates

Is there a way to get every struct members of every values printed in golang template (just like `spew` or `Sprintf("%#v")` or `json.Marshal`) by only modifying the golang template (not the renderer, since the renderer is 3rd party program that already compiled and running)?

the case was, I'm trying to print the `prometheus`'s `alertmanager` correctly, but all I got was

```
Alerts Firing:
- :
- :
- :
- :
```

using this template:

```
*Alerts Firing:*
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}- {{ .Annotations.identifier }}: {{ .Annotations.description }}
{{ end }}
```

Is there a way to get every possible values from `.`?

Comment: You could use custom functions inside the template, would that be enough? Or does that fall under whatever you mean by "renderer"? Or you could use the builtin template func `printf` but the output ain't gonna be formatted like you want it to be.

Comment: For a "quick" view, just use `{{ printf "%#v" .}}`

Comment: Another option would be, if you can't use custom functions, to implement a method on the type of the `.` value that would return a slice of field related info.

Comment: ah that's probably what I need `{{printf "%#v" .}}`

Answer (score 2):

I mean just from looking at it, I would imagine that the issue is that `.identifier` and `.description` are either unexported, or just need to start with a capital letter:

```
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}- {{ .Annotations.identifier }}: {{ .Annotations.description }}
```

probably just needs to be

```
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}- {{ .Annotations.Identifier }}: {{ .Annotations.Description }}
```

or it's a map and you just need to do:

```
{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}- {{ index .Annotations "identifier" }}: {{ index .Annotations "description" }}
```